# Finding a string between two ranges of strings or end of string

Tags: swift, regex

I am trying to extract whatever is between two strings. The first string is a known string, the second string could be from a list of strings.

For example,

We have the start string and the end strings. We want to get the text between these.

```
start = "start"
end = ["then", "stop", "other"]
```

Criteria

```
test = "start a task then do something else"
result = "a task"

test = "start a task stop doing something else"
result = "a task"

test = "start a task then stop"
result = "a task" 

test = "start a task"
result = "a task"
```

I have looked at using a regex, and I got one which works for between two strings, I just cannot create one which words with a option of strings:
`(?<=start\s).*(?=\sthen)`

I have tried using this:
`(?<=start\s).*(?=\sthen|\sstop|\sother)`
but this will include 'then, stop or other' in the match like so:
`"start a task then stop" will return "a task then"`

I have also tried to do a 'match any character except the end list" in the capture group like so: `(?<=start\s)((?!then|stop|other).*)(?=\sthen|\sstop|\sother)` but this has the same effect as the one above.

I am using swift, so I am also wondering whether this can be achieved by finding the substring between two strings.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `(?<=start\s).*?(?=\s+(?:then|stop|other)|$)`

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply, this works perfectly cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=start\s).*?(?=\s+(?:then|stop|other)|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY05lw/1). To search for whole words, add `\b` word boundary in proper places:

```
(?<=\bstart\s).*?(?=\s+(?:then|stop|other)\b|$)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0BP0YH/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=start\s)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `start` string and a whitespace
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+(?:then|stop|other)|$)` - a position in the string that is immediately followed with

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:then|stop|other)` - one of the words
  - `|$`  - or end of string.